# Cygwin Bash, loading a history file

Tags: cygwin, history, bash

I use Cygwin's bash shell (bash -i) daily for common tasks.

In my .bashrc file, I have the following:

```
history -rc bashcommands.history
history
```

Above the first prompt line, I see the list of history commands from `bashcommands.history`, so it looks like the history has been changed.

However, if I now enter `"history"` at the prompt, it shows my original history, not what's in `bashcommands.history`.

If I enter `"history -rc bashcommands.history"` at the prompt, the history file loads as expected, and then `"history"` will show the commands.

Is there some environment or shell settings being reset after `.bashrc` is processed?  I don't see anything in the man pages that would explain it.

How can I get the history file loaded before the first prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are interested, this worked:

1. I set my ENV environment variable to ~/.bashrc
2. I ran the command bash --posix

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried putting it in your .bash_profile?

Comment: .bash_profile and .profile both do nothing.  I placed some echo statements in those files, and they don't show any echoing on the screen.  only .bashrc is processed.